# while ionic serve I'm getting this error "typescript: node_modules/@types/node/worker_threads.d.ts, line: 8 '=' expected. "

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

**My ionic info:**
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.9.0
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.9.0
```

global packages:

```
Cordova CLI : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.4
Cordova Platforms  : android 7.1.4 browser 5.0.3
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
ios-deploy        : 1.10.0 
Node              : v10.13.0
npm               : 6.4.1 
OS                : macOS
Xcode             : Xcode 10.2.1 Build version 10E1001
```

**My Dependency:**

"devDependencies":

{

```
    "@angular/cli": "^6.0.8",
    "@types/node": "^12.7.2",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^4.1.0",
    "increase-memory-limit": "^1.0.3",
    "ws": "3.3.2"
},
```

**My tsconfig.json file**

{
"compilerOptions": {
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
"declaration": false,
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"lib": [
"dom",
"es2015"
],

```
 "module": "es2015",
 "moduleResolution": "node",
 "sourceMap": true,
 "target": "es5",
 "typeRoots": [
   "../node_modules/@types"
 ],
    "types" : ["node"]
 },
  "include": [
      "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
 "exclude": [
   "node_modules",
   "src/**/*.spec.ts",
   "src/**/__tests__/*.ts"
 ],
 "compileOnSave": false,
    "atom": {
      "rewriteTsconfig": false
 }
  //"baseUrl": "src"
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to update Ionic, currently is in version 6:

```
npm uninstall -g ionic 
npm install -g ionic
```

You may also want to update Angular & CLI:

```
ng update @angular/cli @angular/core
```

And, Typescript as well:

```
npm install -g typescript@latest
```